# Lyapunov Function at Fixed Point

Tags: mathematical-modeling, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics

Given the following system:

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = x\left(2-x-y\right)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = x-y$$

I found fixed points $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$. I then want to show that this function is Lyapunov for $x>0$ :

$$V\left(x,y\right)=-\log{x}+x+\frac{1}{2}\left(1-y\right)^{2}$$

One of the characteristics of a Lyapunov function (according to Strogatz) is that $V(x^*) = 0$ where $x^*$ is a fixed point of the system. Obviously $(0,0)$ isn't valid), but plugging in the F.P. $(1,1)$ I get that $V(1,1) = 1$. I'm sure I've just made a silly error but I don't know where it is. After much checking.

Comment: Can't you just subtract $1$ from $V$?

Comment: Why am I able to just do that?

Comment: Well, why not? Would it change whether $V$ is decreasing along tractories or not?

Comment: It wouldn't, but I've been asked to show that this specific function is Lyapunov, i.e. I don't think I'm allowed to change it to make it work.

Comment: In that case I think you'll need to ask for clarification from the person who asked you to show that. If they insist on $V(x^*)=0$, then this function won't do, but that particular detail is rather irrelevant, and a better definition (in my opinion) would be to say that $V$ should have a strict minimum at the equilibrium point.